# Isomorphism classes of abelian groups of certain order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

working on a practice question about finite abelian groups and just want to see if I am on the right track:

> Let $H = <(123)(4567),(8\space 9)(10\space 11),(8\space 11)(9\space 10) > \space  \le
> \sum_{11}$
>
> (a) Show that $H$ is abelian and determine the order.
>
> (b) Give a complete list (without duplications) of all isomorphism
>   classes of abelian groups having order $|H|$.
>
> (c) Determine the isomorphism class of $H$.

For (a), To show that $H$ is abelian, I simply show that each element in the generator of $H$ is commutative with one another. Since every element in $H$ is a combination of these elements - this should be sufficient to show $H$ is abelian.

To determine the order of $H$ I again consider each element of the generator of $H$. If I let $a= (123)(4567)$, $b= (8\space 9)(10\space 11)$, $c=(8\space 11)(9\space 10)$.

Then $a$ has order 12, and $b$, $c$ have order 2. Thus the order of $H$ is 48. With the elements: $a^i$,$a^ib$, $a^ic$, $a^ibc$  ($i = 0,1,...,11$). **Have I got the right idea here?**

For (b):

Since the prime factorisation of $48 = 3 \cdot 2^4$, the complete list is:

$C_3 \times \space C_2 \times \space C_2 \times \space C_2 \times \space C_2 $

$C_3 \times \space C_2 \times \space C_2 \times \space C_{2^2}$

$C_3 \times \space C_2 \times \space C_{2^3}$

$C_3 \times \space C_{2^4}$

$C_3 \times \space C_{2^2} \times \space C_{2^2}$

For (c):

I'm not too sure about this, but does it not just follow from theorem that from the prime factorisation that $H \cong C_3 \times \space C_{2^4}$? (Indeed I did find subgroups of order $3$ and $2^4$, whose direct product is $H$) But do you need to prove that $H$ is not isomorphic to the other classes?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts (a) and (b) look fine.  Though, if this were graded work, I'd want to see a little more argument as to why your enumeration of the elements of $H$ (to determine the order) was complete and non-redundant.

There seems to be a problem with (c). It's fairly clear that $H$ is the direct product $\langle a\rangle\times\langle b,c\rangle$, since the permutation $a$ acts on a different set of points that do $b$ and $c$.  You seem to have already realised that $\langle b,c\rangle\cong C_2\times C_2$.  So your group is $C_{12}\times C_2\times C_2$.  But the $2$-part of the $C_{12}$ yields a further direct factor ($C_4$) for the $2$-part of the whole group $H$.  So the end result should be $C_3\times C_4\times C_2\times C_2$. (I.e., the second on your list.)  It should *not* be necessary to argue that it is not isomorphic to any of the others.  Your list represents a complete and non-redundant enumeration (up to isomorphism) of the abelian groups of order $48$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. For part (c), I realised that I did not have a complete understanding of the classification process of finite abelian groups. For part (a), to add more argument to why the elements of $H$ are non redundant, would it be fair to say: certainly $a^ib$ and $a^ic$ do not overlap, since $b$ and $c$ are distinct. Then, I can also show that $bc$ is distinct from $b$ and $c$, thus $a^ibc$ is again distinct.

Comment: Also, for part (a), working from $H \cong C_3 \times C_{2^2}$, does it hurt to explicitly list what these subgroups are, in the decomposition process?

Comment: @user153663 Yes, that's the idea. Also make sure to think about (e.g.) $a^ib\neq a^jc$, with $i\neq j$, etc.  It's a bit tedious, I'm afraid.  If I were grading the work, I'd just need to see enough to be convinced you understood the issues and could handle all the cases, even if just a few were written out explicitly.

Comment: @user153663 In fact, since $\operatorname{Aut}(\langle b,c\rangle)\cong S_3$ you could, with perfect justification, say, "By symmetry ... ". :-)

Comment: @user153663. For your second comment about part (a), of course, put as much detail as you feel necessary to (at least) convince yourself.  But, I guess there is a typo. We have $\langle a\rangle\cong C_3\times C_{2^2}$, not $H$.

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo. One last thing: I followed an algorithim presented by my teacher to further decompose the 'rough' decomposition of $H \cong C_3 \times C_{2^4} $ by analysing $C_{2^4}$ - i reach the same answer as you provided - but seems like i took a different path. This would be ok right? Thanks so much.

Comment: @user153663. Sure.